# Issues w/ implementing content A/B-testing (browser-only) using GTM and GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I followed the directions as per https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side for two separate pages: the homepage and another main item.

On these pages I just want to test two types of content. I set up the experiments in GA, wrapped the content I wanted to swap out in an element with a custom ID, added custom HTML to the GTM Tag, and set up two triggers; one for the homepage and one for the other item, both set up for the URL to be an exact match with the actual URL. I've also set it up so that GA fires before the A/B-test.

The problem I'm not having is that while the homepage works fine, the main item also swaps out its original content for the content from the homepage variant. And that's where I'm stuck: it seems my main item tag is also activated by the homepage trigger, even though I've set it to be an equal match. I've even added an extra rule to the homepage trigger by adding a part of the path for non-homepage items which shouldn't appear in the homepage URL, but that doesn't seem to help either.

Which makes me wonder; can I only use this set up (browser-only implementation) once per GTM/GA account? Or is there still something wrong with my trigger?

Answer (score 0):

what you could do here is add the other item trigger as a exception / blocking for homepage
and homepage trigger as an exception / blocking for other item

Here is how you can learn a bit more about triggers
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106961?hl=en

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried that (not mutually exclusive though, then again, the issue only persists on non-homepage items).